# The relationship between density of a metal and the magnitude of it's magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields

I was just doing a little review on E&M and I was just wondering if there was any correlation between the density ($\rho$) of a metal and how large a magnetic field is.

I know that more dense metals have stronger Magnetic Fields. But with an increase in the metal's density, and therefore it's strength, would there be any significant increase in the field's magnitude or would a higher density result in a smaller sized field?

Unfortunately, both parts of that question make intuitive sense and I am just trying to rule out the wrong intuition by asking those who have a stronger background on the topic. (ie $ \ \uparrow  \rho\  = \  \uparrow$ field size   or   $ \ \uparrow \rho \ = \ \downarrow \ $field size)

Although now I am a Math major, I don't really remember ever discussing anything about the size of a magnetic field in any of the physics classes that I've taken during my time at University.

Comment: you wrote "I know that more dense metals have stronger Magnetic Fields." can you give an example what you have in mind?

Comment: I do not know a pure metal with a significant magnetic field, normally they have spin polarized domains. The density means several physical quantities, dense transition metals are not magnetic.

Comment: sorry, I didn't even realize how vague that statement was. I read a pretty good analogy one time that seemed to summarize what I mean.
"Yes, if you put a bunch of small magnets in a foam sphere and then squeezed the foam there would be the same amount of magnet but in a smaller volume = stronger field" but with that, does the actual size of the field increase or decrease?

Thanks!